# Running 10-3 wire into a junction box that has 12-2 wire from a different circuit

Tags: wiring, junction-box

I’m wondering if code allows 10-3 wire in a junction box containing 12-2 wire from a different circuit? I’ve run out of room to install a separate junction box for a 10-3 splice that was taped together. I’m trying to correct the problem as it was left taped outside of its required junction box. Thank you!

Comment: How big is the junction box in question? There's nothing expressly prohibiting more than one circuit in a box, but it needs to be big enough to hold all the wires you're trying to stuff in it!

Comment: Not only big enough to hold them but be sized large enough to meet the box fill requirements. The numbers of #12 and the number of number10s including the grounds and the size of the box and any devices in the box will be needed to calculate the box fill.

Answer (score 2):

The NEC doesn't prevent multiple hot cables entering a box.

The NEC has a box fill calculation based on wire sizes entering the box. Circuit conductor #10's require 2.5 in³ per conductor, #12's require 2.25 in³.

In the 2020 NEC grounds count particularly odd:

> 314.16(B)(5) Equipment Grounding Conductor Fill. Where up to four equipment grounding conductors or equipment bonding jumpers enter a
> box, a single volume allowance in accordance with Table 314.16(B)
> shall be made based on the largest equipment grounding conductor or
> equipment bonding jumper entering the box. A ¼ volume allowance shall
> be made for each additional equipment grounding conductor or equipment
> bonding jumper that enters the box, based on the largest equipment
> grounding conductor or equipment bonding conductor.

There are additional requirements for devices mounted in the box (+2 count of largest conductor), fittings and other conditions. A picture would help to identify those possible applicable additions. But the bare minimum size you describe with 2@12/2 and 2@10/3 would require a box with 26.5 in³ capacity. (4x2.25 plus 7x2.5)

Comment: Note to the OP that somewhere inside the box in question there should be a permanent indication of the box size stamped or molded into it. It may be encoded in the boxes model/product ID, but it'll be there. If necessary, look up the brand & model # on line to find out how many cubic inches the box is to see if it meets requirements.